# Heroku deploy error Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile

Tags: java, spring, database, maven, heroku

With my team we are trying to deploy rental service web app on heroku.
Here is our problem:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project Nordic-Motorhomes: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

!     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
!     Push failed

application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=${driver}
spring.datasource.url=${url}
spring.datasource.username=${username}
spring.datasource.password=${password}
server.port=7070
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>Nordic-Motorhomes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Nordic-Motorhomes</name>
    <description>Nordic-Motorhomes</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You are not using JDK 17 on contradiction what your configuration is requiring.. `invalid target release: 17 ->` ...

Comment: Also I would recommend to use the most recent version of spring boot 2.7.0 instead...